# Youtube plugin in Totem first loads and then plays the video?

Tags: 10.04, plugins, youtube, totem

In Totem the youtube plugin first loads all the video, taking a lot of time for a video of 5 minutes. Only when all the video is loaded it starts playing it.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Totem with that plugin, but I don't think that is normal, because I develop an extension for Firefox, called [FlashVideoReplacer](http://www.webgapps.org/addons/flashvideoreplacer), that loads YouTube videos with other plugins or standalone players and it doesn't require the video to be fully loaded before playing it. Give it a try. Please read the compatibility notes. I recommend using gecko-mediaplayer and smplayer.

Comment: If I install Firefox I'll try it. I'm actually using Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I use FlashVideoReplacer add-on to play Youtube videos through Totem Browser Plugin 2.30.1 using GStreamer 0.10.28 and I also have this problem, but only when playing flv. Go to FlashVideoReplacer settings and choose MEDIUM quality and "prefer mp4 over flv".